# Focus order between fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

In my app, I'm having fragments inside an activity. The number and type (layout) of these fragments are dynamic also.

My problem is, that I can't really set focus order between fragments (see screenshot).

[image]

When EditText 1/1 has focus (and onscreenkeyboard is displayed) inside Fragment #1, and the user hits "Next" then EditTest 2/2 in Fragment #2 gets focus, however I want EditText 2/1 to have focus.

I could make 2/1->2/2 to work, but I can't make 1/1->2/1 to work (1/1->2/2 is the current scenario :( ).

**Also it can happen (as number of fragments are dynamic), that I have a fragment #3 with the same layout.xml as Fragment #2, so again with 2 EditBoxes.
In this case I need to have the following "Next" focus order:
1/1 -> 2/1 -> 2/2 -> 3/1 -> 3/2**

I'd like a solution which does not require code, is it possible to define such relationship inside the layout.xmls of the fragments?